# Method to save money which disallows early withdrawal?

Tags: savings, certificate-of-deposit

How can money be saved that can't be accessed -- even in an emergency -- for 6 months? I'm aware of CDs, but in an emergency banks allow you to get the money on the CD, and will charge you to access the funds early. Is there a method to save money that absolutely disallows accessing it for at least 6 months?

The answer does not have to involve using banks. Perhaps someone knows of an out-of-the-box way to accomplish this task.

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps it's possible to get a money order for x amount of dollars and mail the money order to myself. But how to make sure it takes 6 months to get to me?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you try to solve here? Do you believe you will use the money otherwise but want to make sure you save a certain sum? My two cents, not having access to money in an emergency can backfire.

Comment: @Yes, I want the certainty of knowing I can't access the money for a period of 6 months. It's possible it could backfire for some people, but not for me.

Comment: Ok, but if you are certain you are not running short on cash, why worry about you accessing it? After all, if you don't need it, what's the purpose of trying to access it?

Comment: @I'd rather not address my motives. I think the question can get some interesting answers without requiring a motivating factor.

Comment: There are two possibilities. a) you give it to someone with no record in which case they can keep it if they are so inclined and you'll have a lot of trouble getting it back. b) you give it to someone/some organisation with a record in which case you can use that record to borrow now against the money that will be paid to you at that future date.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't know that I'd want to borrow against the money. Just want the money to not be accessible to me for 6 months. Any recommendations for organizations that would keep the money and under no circumstances allow me to access the money for 6 months?

Comment: a) we don't do recommendations b) you will always be able to borrow against that money and that's the same as being able to access it isn't it? If not then we do need to know your motivations don't we?

Comment: @RobertLongson What about the money order idea I mentioned. Is there a way to mail a money order to yourself, so that it doesn't arrive before a specified date?

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't see why motivation would matter. The question could be treated as a theoretical.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't want to do anything with the money, including borrowing against it. I just want to not be able to access it in any way for 6 months. Maybe I'm being naive but is this question unanswerable, in your view, if the motivation is unknown? Obviously it's to help me save money, but doing so in an unorthodox fashion.

Comment: You could write yourself a bank-guaranteed check and sent it in an hyperbolic event into the exosphere - if you get the right angle, velocity, maximum height & gravitation you could have your check reenter in 6 months from now and cash it in..

Comment: @whitewings the motivation matters because it affects how foolproof the scheme needs to be. You seem to think that you might try to get access to the money before your self-imposed limit. Any method to thwart that needs to consider how far you might be willing to go and what costs you might be willing to incur to defeat it. You also need to consider how much risk of the money not being returned you are willing to take. E.g, you could just loan the money to another party, with the principal payable on a specified date, but if the other party goes bankrupt, then you won't get your money back.

Comment: The problem is that *your money* is, by definition, ***your money***.  You have access to your money, even if it takes some work to get to it.

Comment: @Nobody My motivation is that I need a better savings scheme than the savings schemes I'm aware of, that all allow me to access the money in an emergency. Or I need to do the simpler thing, and learn to budget and save money better. Still I'm interested in answers to the question.

Comment: You asked here and again as a comment to the one current answer about mailing for 6 months. That is not a money question- One could ask the same about mailing anything you want at a future time. Also anything that gets lost in yeh mail for 6 months may be gone for good. The answer sticking to money is CD which you reject and maybe escrow. Everything else is a hack and not specific to money.

Comment: How about lock it as cash in a safe to which only you have the key, then rent the safe to a trusted friend with a non-rescindable 6 month lease. Or lock it as cash in your house and get yourself convicted of a crime that has a 6 month jail term. Lock cash in a safe and give the only key to a trusted friend and send them on a 6 month cruise. Bury it in the ground in another country and get yourself a 6-month ban.  Crazy hacks are infinite. Standard use of the monetary system is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open a [Letter of Credit](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/letterofcredit.asp) that names you as the beneficiary.**

Deposit your funds with a commercial bank that handles letters of credit. Name yourself as the beneficiary. The letter of credit terms should make it payable only after a certain date, such as six months in the future. (If the bank does not offer date-maturing letters of credit, make the terms something dependent on the date, such as payable upon presentation of page 1 of the New York Times for the date of your choice.)

At that point, since the bank must guarantee that the funds will be available to be paid to you in the future, they will freeze your account. You won't be able to withdraw the funds under any circumstances. Not even a hissy fit will unlock your account.

When the payable date arrives, present the letter of credit and proper identification to the bank, and they will pay the funds to you, minus fees.

Comment: Very interesting response, best so far. I see that banks charge a little under 1% of the money deposited, which is fine. Can this be done on a routine basis, like 1 or 2 new letters of credit a month?

Comment: @whitewings For a commercial bank with an L/C department, it's completely routine. They'll do as many letters of credit as you wish, and will happily collect the fees from you.

Comment: Have you ever heard of someone using this method to save money? Or is it a novel idea?

Comment: @whitewings I've only used L/Cs in international trade as described in the link above. I've heard of them being used onshore as a way to guarantee performance on a contract when both sides have a lot to lose if the other side fails to fulfill its obligation and the usual legal remedies for breaking a contract would not make the aggrieved party whole. Saving money? Nope.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking either for an escrow service, or if you don't have the money fr the service you need a trusted person that would provide this service for free.

When somebody makes an earnest money deposit when they make a bid for a house, the money doesn't directly go to the seller, and the buyer can't get the money back unless both sides agree that certain conditions have been met. A 3rd party holds the funds.

You need to find an organization that provides this service in situations like yours. There will have to be paperwork involved to protect you and them. That paperwork will define the conditions that have to be met to release the funds.

I have no idea of the costs involved. If this is a lot of money, you might need to get your lawyer involved.

This will leave a paper trail. This will not shield money from the courts, the government, or your ex.  If this is seen as a way to deceive a party that has a right to know about the money the courts will be very interested in that aspect.

Comment: Would this really work?  Escrow is normally used when two or more parties might have a possible claim to the money, contingent on some future events.  If there is only one party involved, then it's not at all clear that they are obliged to hold it until some fixed date, especially if you showed up and asked for it early. Imagine you're holding the escrowed money in a scenario like this, and the rightful owner shows up and threatens to sue you if you don't return it right now. Are you going to court to defend this wacky arrangement, or are you just giving him his money and showing him the door?

Comment: Neither of these options appeal to me. Huh, I thought this would be an easy question to answer, with lots of ideas I would like. I guess I could bury the money in some remote location that would be a pain for me to get to until the 6 months are up. Even that wouldn't really work. If I was super desperate to get the money I would still be able to get it.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep How about the idea of mailing myself a money order that would take 6 months to reach me? Is there any way to send mail to yourself that would take months to get to you?

Comment: Unless you have a trusted friend/family member any arrangement that is effective at preventing you from accessing your money is not going to be cheap because it is not a common need. More prudent would be to address the real issue at play here, whatever that is.

Comment: How long areoney orders good for, anyway? US checks time out in 90 days unless the bank is feeling generous

Comment: @whitewings you would have to insure the item you are mailing so that if it gets lost the money isn't gone.  I don't think there is a way to have an item delivered on a specific date, short of paying somebody to hold it for you.

Comment: @Nobody there are companies that provide an escrow service for the private sale of a car, They might do it for other transactions. I would think that you could specify a date that must have past in order to complete the terms of release.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Thanks for the answer, but MTA's answer is the only one that sounds good.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Again, with the sale of a car there are two parties involved. The money has to be released to the seller if the car is transferred and returned to the buyer if it isn't. It's not at all clear that in the case where there is only one party involved that the escrow service won't just give you the money back if you ask for it.  Though, now that I think about it, I suppose you could create a phony second party, such as an LLC that you control.

Answer (score 2):

As long as it is your money, you'll have unrestricted access to it - because it is yours.

You'll need to give the money to someone else.

> Perhaps someone knows of an out-of-the-box way to accomplish this task

Of course. Create a trust, lay out the conditions you want in the trust, and nominate a trustee to execute these conditions. The money is then transferred to the trust and is no longer yours.

Depending on your jurisdiction, there may be some tax consequences for that. And, of course, legal fees and trustee fees etc.

That said, this sounds to me like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).